# Ubuntu cannot reach host when linking docker containers

Tags: macos, docker, ubuntu, networking

I have 3 dockerized services. Services A and B run inside same docker-compose file:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  service_a:
    container_name: service_a
    networks:
      - my_net
  service_b:
    container_name: service_b
    networks:
      - my_net
networks: #This is just because I wanted to change the network default name
  my_net:
    name: my_net
```

Service C needs make requests against services A and B, but it runs separately using docker without compose (that's because I'm passing `--network` option). So, I run service C linking A and B:

```
docker run --network my_net --link service_a --link service_b service_c_docker_image
```

This is working on MacOS, but not in Ubuntu!

If I run ping command, instead of default service_c_docker_image command:

```
docker run --network my_net --link service_a --link service_b service_c_docker_image ping service_a
```

on MacOS, the host is reached properly; on Ubuntu, I get: `ping: service_a: Name or service not known`. And same with `service_b`.

Both machines are using same version of docker and docker-compose.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me. Actually, my configuration is right but services A and B were not run because an application level error, so links were not working.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a typo in your question as that compose file should not run at all, the service level network names `my_net` should match the top level network name which then can be renamed using `name: intra_net`. The network set in the `docker run` command should match what the network was renamed to in the top level networks section (and that network needs to already exist, so run the compose stack first).

working example:

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  service_a:
    image: odise/busybox-curl
    command: ["curl", "-s", "service_b:5678"]
    depends_on:
      - service_b
    networks:
      - my_net
  service_b:
    image: hashicorp/http-echo
    command: ["-text", "hello world"]
    networks:
  - my_net
networks:
  my_net:
    name: infra_network
```

Run the services `docker-compose up -d` and check the logs:

```
> docker-compose logs
Attaching to docker-compose-networks_service_a_1, docker-compose-networks_service_b_1
service_b_1  | 2019/01/06 05:53:55 Server is listening on :5678
service_b_1  | 2019/01/06 05:53:55 service_b:5678 172.19.0.3:46900 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 12 "curl/7.39.0" 106.6µs
service_a_1  | hello world
```

Then start the other container with docker

```
> docker run --network infra_network odise/busybox-curl curl -s service_b:5678
hello world
```